# Hill's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $p(x)$ be a periodic function with period $1$, i.e. $p(x+1) = p(x)$.

Let also $y(x)$ be a non-trivial solution of the equation
$$y''(x) + p(x) y(x) = 0$$
that satisfies $y(0) = y(1) = 0$.

I want to prove that $y(x+1) = C y(x)$

*Proof*: As $p$ is periodic, it's not difficult to see that if $y(x)$ is a solution, then $y(x+1)$ is also a solution. Compute the Wronskian
$$W[y(x), y(x+1)] = y(x) y'(x+1) - y'(x) y(x+1)$$

Therefore $W[y(0), y(1)] = y(0) y'(1) - y'(0) y(1) = 0$, as $y(0) = y(1) = 0$.

By Liouville-Ostogradsky formula we have
$$W(x) = W(x_0) e^{-\int_{x_0}^{x} p(\tau) \, d \tau}$$
for the equation $y''(x) + p(x) y'(x) + q(x) y(x) = 0$ with solutions $y_1(x), \ldots, y_n(x)$ and $W(x) := W(y_1(x), \ldots, y_n(x))$.

So in the case $y_1 := y(x)$, $y_2 := y(x+1)$, $y'' + q y = 0$, we have $W(x) = W(x_0)$ and therefore Wronskian is constant. As $W(0) = 0$, the previous claim implies that $W \equiv 0$, which implies the linear dependence of $y(x), y(x+1)$.

*end of the proof*

Is the proof correct?

Comment: It is a little bit long. You could also just observe that $y'(1)=Cy'(0)$ and get the linear dependence directly from there.